# What does '^' do in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

It seems like a simple question but what does the '^' do in batch? I'm doing something similar to the following code (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229947/is-it-possible-for-a-batch-file-to-delete-a-file-if-not-found-in-list-from-text)).  The file someFile.txt contains names of files to save and 'folder' is a directory from which to delete all files **not** mentioned in someFile.txt.  Why does this code not work when `^` is removed from `^|` in the `for` statement.  Additionally, why can't the expression following `do` be wrapped in `()` to create a longer expression?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set folder="c:\somePath"
set excludeFile="c:\somePath2\someFile.txt"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d %folder% ^| findstr /vibg:%excludeFile%') do del "%folder%\%%F"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^ escapes the next char to take away all special meaning. the ^ stops the pipe from imediatly piping. the do can be wraped like so:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d %folder% ^| findstr /vibg:%excludeFile%') do (del "%folder%\%%F")
```

Comment: so ^ allows dir expression to evaluate before piping?  And about he (), does the expression inside () need to stay on the same line or something? O i get it, because the its a string, '|' would cause immediate exit

Comment: yup. the first half of the for would imediatly pipe to the sencond half without starting the for.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to print special characters.

From WikiPedia:

Some characters, such as pipe ("|") characters, have special meaning to the command line. They cannot be printed as text using the ECHO command unless escaped using the caret ^ symbol:

```
C:\> Echo foo | bar
'bar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\> Echo foo ^| bar
foo | bar
```

Not sure about the do () thing though

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file