# Batch file to delete files with relative name contained in text list?

Tags: batch-file

I need a bat to delete all files with the RELATIVE name contained in a text file

In the files directory the files are named like:

```
1_a.jpg
1_b.jpg
1_c.jpg
2_a.jpg
3_a.jpg
3_b.jpg
```

In the file list to delete the RELATIVE name is

```
2
3
```

I want to delete all files contains 2 and 3 (specified in file list)

After deletion remain in my folder these files (bacause not contain 2 or 3)

```
1_a.jpg
1_b.jpg
1_c.jpg
```

I tryed a batch files but i need to reverse it because this bat do not remove the files specified in text list

```
@echo off
setlocal
set folder="c:\somePath"
set excludeFile="c:\somePath2\someFile.txt"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d %folder% ^| findstr /vibg:%excludeFile%') do del "%folder%\%%F"
```

Can you help me please?

Here there are the code to reverse to delete the files only in text list.

[Is it possible for a batch file to delete a file if not found in list from text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229947/is-it-possible-for-a-batch-file-to-delete-a-file-if-not-found-in-list-from-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do echo del "*%%a*"
```

For each element in the file, delete files containing the indicated text in its name.

The `del` commands are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo`.

Comment: Hi how can i set the path folder contains the files to delete ?

Comment: @placidomaio, you can use `del "c:\somewhere\*%%a*"` or, if you have the folder in a variable,  `del "%folder%\*%%a*"`, or you can, before the `for` command, use a `cd` or a `pushd` to change the current active directory

Comment: Your solution works, it's possibile to add a prevent check control to prevent to delete inexistent files ? if I have in text list a words and do not exist a specified files ? Example if in list i add 9 there are not a file with name contains 9.

Comment: @placidomaio, `if exist "c:\somewhere\*%%a*" del "c:\somewhere\*%%a*"`, or simply forget about check and hide the "error" message with `del "c:\somewhere\*%%a*" 2>nul ` (the same works for the rest of the options in previous comments)

Comment: Thanks your solution working like a charm, many thanks you are a great coder. Have a nice day and thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Where LIST is the name of the file with the "2" and "3"

```
pushd %folder%
for /f %%a in (%LIST%) do @del %%a_*.jpg
popd
```

To delete all but those files, first make a list of the files that match, then using the FOR you had, delete everything else:

```
set folder=C:\somepath\subdir
set LIST=C:\somepath\list.txt
set excludeFile=C:\somepath\tmp.txt
if exist %excludeFile% del %excludeFile%

for /f %%a in (%LIST%) do (
    dir %%a_*.jpg > nul && dir /b %%a_*.jpg >> %excludeFile%
)

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d %folder% ^| findstr /vibg:%excludeFile%') do del "%folder%\%%F"
```