# Batch File to Delete all Matching Files from All Folders then Save it in a Log.txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, delete-file

I want to create a Batch File that will delete a File that has any of the two names such as "new" or "1234" of any file format.

this is my *file.txt:*

```
new
1234
```

this is what I want to happen:

[image: Files that I want to Delete]

I already tried some of the codes I found online but It deleted some of my files. So I'm scared to re-run codes that has such WildCards hehe.

So far I have this:

```
SET FILENAME=DeleteLog.txt

SET USERLOG=%USERPROFILE%\%FILENAME%
rem I just declared the Downloads for safety-purposes but it should be C:\
SET TARGET1=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads

echo STARTING THE FILE DELETION >>%USERLOG%

cd %TARGET1%
rem file.txt contains the string (new,1234)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do echo del %TARGET1%*%%a* >>%USERLOG%

echo FINISHING THE FILE DELETION >>%USERLOG%
```

My Logic is:
For every file(new,1234).txt on my C:\ Drive -> Delete -> Log

I'm trying to follow this but it does not work for me:
[Batch file to delete files with relative name contained in text list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033794/batch-file-to-delete-files-with-relative-name-contained-in-text-list)
What seems to be the problem?

Any tips and suggestion will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try for this batch script and if it's OK you can remove the `ECHO(` before `Del` command :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Delete some files with pattern *123* or *new*
Set "CurrentFolder=%~dp0"
Set "Pattern=*123* *new*"
cd /d "%CurrentFolder%"
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Main
cls
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
REM Count total files and store into array
set /a "Count=0"
@for %%f in (%Pattern%) do (
    set /a "Count+=1"
    set "list[!Count!]=%%f"
)
REM disply files
@for /L %%a in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo( [%%a] - "!list[%%a]!"
)
Echo( -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Echo( Total pattern files found are equal to %Count% on this folder : "%CurrentFolder%"
Echo( -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo(
If [%Count%] EQU [0] color 0C & echo( There are No Files that matches this %Pattern% in this Folder "%CurrentFolder%" & TimeOut /T 10 /NoBreak>nul & Exit /B 1
echo( Type "DELAll" in order to delete all files found here "%CurrentFolder%" with this "%Pattern%" ...
echo( Or Type only the number of file that you want to delete ...

set /p "Input="

@For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        Cls & Call :DeleteFile "!list[%%i]!"
    )
    
    If /I "%Input%" == "Delall" (
        cls & Call :DeleteFile "!list[%%i]!"
    )
)
EndLocal & Goto Main
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:DeleteFile <FilePath>
echo( ----------------------------------
Echo( Deleting "%~nx1"
ECHO( Del "%~1"
echo( ----------------------------------
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, this is very useful and so cool :)
Although I'm trying to access the C: Drive by replacing the `%~dp0` by `C:` well probably its wrong, cuz it's not searching recursively...

Comment: @jeriru at line 12 just add `/r` for seaching recursively like that `@for /r %%f in (%Pattern%).....`