# A batch file to delete a file if (a part) of its filename is not found in a text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have studied this: [Is it possible for a batch file to delete a file if not found in list from text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229947/is-it-possible-for-a-batch-file-to-delete-a-file-if-not-found-in-list-from-text)

In my case there is a list of words (one in each line) in a text file e.g:

```
ext
abcd
```

in which there are extensions of the files (like `ext` above) or fragments of filenames' bases (like `abcd` above).

So, I don't want files like `*abcd*` or `*ext*` to be deleted (where `*` is for any number of any allowed characters) - and I do want to delete any other files from the directory.

I took this code:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "SomeFolder" ^| findstr /vibg:"ExcludeFile"') do del "SomeFolder\%%F"
```

and what I did to it - I deleted `/b` option of `findstr` (so now it is
`...findstr /vig...` - so as I think `findstr` shoud try to match strings from the list (.txt file) to any part of the 8.3 filenames in directory. But it does not. It does not exclude files witch matching extensions from deleting, (it deletes for instance `antything.ext` despite the string `ext` is in the list). Can you help please?

PS Thanks for trailing spaces, it helped - is it possible to use an implication of two conditions e.g a file would be deleted if:

1. a part of filename **is not** on exclude list
2. and a file **has** a specific extension (let's say `.bmp`).

In above example the file `123.xyz` would be deleted because of the first condition (not a part of it is `abcd` nor `ext`), but would not be actually because of the second condition (it's extension is not `.bmp`)?

Comment: check if there are trailing spaces in the textfile.

Comment: You may also want to get a really in depth explanation of `FINDSTR` by reading [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: I think your best bet would be to make all of the search strings in the search file as regular expressions and then get rid of the `/B` option as one of the arguments.

Comment: You would want the search strings in your search file to be `.*abcd.*` and `.*\.ext$`

Comment: Thank you Stephan - there were railing spaces ideed. Problem solved by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in your Exclude File.

```
.*abcd.*
.*\.ext$
```

Remove the `/B` option from the `FINDSTR` command.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "SomeFolder" ^| findstr /vig:"ExcludeFile"') do del "SomeFolder\%%F"
```

I would read the help for the `FINDSTR` command so that you understand what the regular expressions are doing in your exclude list.  Here is brief list of the options I used.

```
.        Wildcard: any character
*        Repeat: zero or more occurrences of previous character or class
$        Line position: end of line
\x       Escape: literal use of metacharacter x
```

Comment: Thank, although the problem was because of trailing spaces, I will try this.

Comment: @maccam however unlikely it might be you could have a file name with one of your file extensions as part of the file name.  So just using your example you could have `Court_Text.pdf` would match your exclude list and not get deleted.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I do understand this problem and I will implement your advice, although the data format is restricted to maybe a dozen of possible filenames (except  some of them are YYYYMMDD or HHMMSS format generated everyday) and maybe 5 or 7 extensions. But I will do it just to sleep easy.

Comment: well, this works brilliant. Thanks again.